# special test bit function in C

Tags: c

```
/* Returns 1 if the corresponding bit in the given seq_bits indicates true
 * and curr_seqno is within range of last_seqno. Otherwise returns 0.
 */
static inline int samle_test_bit(const unsigned long *seq_bits,
                  uint32_t last_seqno, uint32_t curr_seqno)
{
    int32_t diff;

    diff = last_seqno - curr_seqno;
    if (diff < 0 || diff >= TQ_LOCAL_WINDOW_SIZE)
        return 0;
    else
        return test_bit(diff, seq_bits) != 0;
}
```

curr_seqno=current sequence number
 last_seqno=last sequence number

I don't understand this function. It seems like always testing bit 1 because diff=last_seqno-curr_seqno mostly 1.  test_bit(1, seq_bits)

what if you want to test other bits in the seq_bits?

Comment: you are confused.  The code is taken from here https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/experimental/android-3.8/net/batman-adv/bitarray.h and the function is not called test_bit, it is called batadv_test_bit, and calls test_bit.  So this is a wrapper around test_bit which adds some range checking of unclear nature.

Comment: @MK, what do you think of the diff, seems like it's always 1.

Comment: Not sure what this function is doing but whatever it is, it is not testing for bits. And if `diff` will be 1 or not it depends on the value of other variables you are inputting in the function.

Answer (score 0):

The function is checking that the difference between last_seqno and curr_seqno are smaller than TQ_LOCAL_WINDOW_SIZE and that curr_seqno is not > than last_seqno.

It looks like validation but you changed something as the 2nd call doesn't match the protype of the apparently tail recursive call.  In K&R C, you could sometimes get away with local variables used as paramters by mistake but this example you provide gets the types wrong.. so as posted this is NONSENSE!  *

- Seen explanation that this is a wrapper not meant to be a recursive call.

Comment: sequence number is like 1, 2, 3,4,5 ........ curr_seqno should be always > than last_seqno so it will return 0 most of the time. the test_bit will not be executed.

Comment: I see MK's comment, so it's a wrapper, presumably test_bit() can be eitehr expensive or only required in particular circumstances